# Connect existing git repo with files on new server?

Tags: git

Up until very recently, I had a website on a git-less server and theme files would be updated via sftp. I kept a copy of all changes checked into a github repo.

The website was recently migrated to a server with git installed, so I'd like to hook up the files with the repo and run 'git pull' when updates are made (via my local) to the repo.

What is the best way to connect the repo with the theme files on the new server?

Reinitialize, or simply remove the theme files from the server and run `git clone <repo>`?

Comment: Why do you need to remove anything before git clone? It should simply merge with the existing files

Comment: If you've been using FTP, you potentially gave away your login password. Change all your passwords, security audit your machine, and [never use FTP again](http://engineering.deccanhosts.com/2013/02/why-is-ftp-insecure.html). Use SFTP or SSH, possibly via something like [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/), or git via SSH or HTTPS.

Comment: oops i'm a dumby, I have been using SFTP & cyberduck. will edit to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize a new repository in the production directory, but if anything goes wrong it might screw up the production server. Instead, do as little work as possible on the production directory.

It's simplest and safest thing to first ensure the repository has the same stuff as in production.

1. Make a fresh clone of the repo.
2. Copy all the production files there.
3. Sift through any differences and commit as appropriate.
4. Push.

Once that's done we now know production has the same files as in the repo. Instead of moving the whole production directory, you can simply move the `.git` directory.

1. Configure your server to deny serving files in `.git/`
2. Copy `.git/` from the clone to the production directory.
3. Verify everything is fine with `git status` in the production directory.